# Can I get a keyboard shortcut to go to homepage of current website in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, alfred

I'm looking for a way to set a keyboard shortcut to go to the current homepage of the website I'm browsing in Chrome at that time.

So for example I'm on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?wizard=1" right now. "Press shortcut" Url "https://stackoverflow.com/" loads.

Could be a chrome plugin or an Alfred workflow.

Comment: Don't you mean Alfred workflow?

Comment: Oh yes sorry haha, yes I mean Alfred workflow.

Comment: Do you want the home page open in a new tab or the same tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Alfred workflow and connect a [Hotkey](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/triggers/hotkey/) trigger to a [Run NSAppleScript](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/actions/run-nsapplescript/) action adding the following code to the latter:

```
on alfred_script(q)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set theURL to URL of active tab of window 1
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
        set theHomeURL to text item 1 of theURL & "//" & text item 3 of theURL
        set URL of active tab of window 1 to theHomeURL
        activate
    end tell
end alfred_script
```

Don't forget to set a hotkey combination to the trigger.

Comment: This doens't seem to work. Are there any important options I need to change to make this work?

Comment: @DigitalGentleman, I don't have Chrome installed, so I tried a code that works with Safari. After doing a research I edited the code with a minor change that might work for Chrome. Could you try again? If it still doesn't work I will install Chrome to make the changes to fix it.